# CakePHP 2.0 - virtualFields are not used on find operation with options

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.0 and I have a Model with this 'virtualFields':

Country.php:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'path' => "CONCAT_WS('/', dirname, basename)"
);
```

If I do this in a Controller which uses "User"

```
$users = $this->User->find('all');
```

the virtual field `path` is set.

If I use this in my Controller, which also uses "User"

```
$options['fields'] = array(
    'DISTINCT User.*'
);
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'courses',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id = courses.user_id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'times',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'courses.id = times.course_id'
        )
    )
);
$options['conditions'] = array(
    'times.amount > ' => 0
);

$users = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

With the options, the `path` field is not set, of course, the SQL query does not seem to have the "CONCAT_WS('/', dirname, basename)" field included, which is included if I do the `find` operation without the options.

What can I do having the options, so that the virtual field is automatically included? Of course I can write in the `fields` options the CONCAT, but that's not very nice, especially if I change it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by rather than distinct and remove the fields option completely.

```
$options['group'] = array(
    'User.*'
);
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'courses',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id = courses.user_id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'times',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'courses.id = times.course_id'
        )
    )
);
$options['conditions'] = array(
    'times.amount > ' => 0
);

$users = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```